# Microsoft Cognitive Services custom vision - use without prediction API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I'm currently looking to use Microsoft Cognitive Service [custom vision](https://www.customvision.ai/). It comes with a [prediction API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/use-prediction-api) which you can use to fetch the predicted results. Is it possible to use Custom Vision without using this prediction API? With that, I mean just export the model to Tensorflow and build my own API which fetches the results directly from Tensorflow.

It seems like I can export the model for mobile usage or to run it in a Docker container. However it seems like the prediction API is wired into that Docker container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom Vision Service only exports compact domains. Classifiers built with a compact domain may be slightly less accurate than a standard domain with the same amount of training data.After you have exported your TensorFlow model from the Custom Vision Service, this [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/export-model-python) will show you how to use this model locally to classify images.

For object detection exports there is code to load and run the object detection model in the zip file downloaded. Along with the the export model you will find Python code to exercise the model.